# Windows hello for business: remove certificate from virtual smartcard

Tags: windows, certificate, windows-command-prompt, microsoft-intune, smartcard

I've managed to add a certificate to windows hello for signin to RDP.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/rdp-sign-in?tabs=intune

However during testing i've generated a few faulty certificates, i would like to clean them up.

If i use `certutil -delkey -csp  "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider" "ID"`  i get the message that the smartcard is read-only.

How can i clean up the certificates on the virtual smartcard provided by windows hello?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `certutil -csp NGC -key` to list all credentials stored in windows hello for business.
Then I used `certutil -csp NGC -delkey <name>` to remove the ones that did not have `login.windows.net` in the name to clean up all other credentials.

This was not a 100% fix for me as intune seemed to have restored some of the old certificates, but at least i can manage the situation now.